# Tooltip in gridview

Tags: gridview, tooltip, code-behind

complete novice at work (who is also ill and feeling particularly thick)

I have the following code that gives me a generic "tool tip text" for each heading in a gridview....great.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header) 
    { 
        foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells) 
        { 
            foreach (System.Web.UI.Control ctl in cell.Controls) 
            { 
                if (ctl.GetType().ToString().Contains("DataControlLinkButton")) 
                { 
                    cell.Attributes.Add(
                        "title", "tooltip text for " + ((LinkButton)ctl).Text);
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

What is not so great is that I obviously don't want all of the cells to return the same generic ' tooltip text for'.

How would a simpleton like me adapt the code so that for the ProductID heading cell the tt says "a unique product reference", for a Product Description heading cell the tt returns "description of the the product".

Apologies for the dim question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the tooltip to be set corresponding to the column title ?

You could do something like this :

```
if (ctl.GetType().ToString().Contains("DataControlLinkButton")) 
{
    String headerText = cell.Text;
    cell.Attributes.Add("title", headerTooltips[headerText]);
}
```

where `headerTooltips` is a dictionary defined before :

```
Dictionary<String, String> headerTooltips = new Dictionary<String, String>();
headerTooltips["Product ID"] = "A unique product ID";
[...]
```

Comment: Hello Wookai..I have tried this but I get a "The given key was not present in the dictionary." on the 'cell.attributes.add('title'...' line...any ideas why?

Comment: Maybe you did not create the dictionary with the right keys ? How do you construct it ? Try to print headerText et see if it corresponds to what you used to create the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [TemplateField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.aspx):

```
<asp:GridView ...>
   ...
   <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
         <a href='<%# Eval("ProductID", "Edit.aspx?{0}") %>' title='<%# Eval("ProductDescription") %>'><%# Eval("ProductID") %></a>
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   ...
</asp:GridView>
```

[More about using Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can something like this.

http://rosshawkins.net/archive/2007/04/15/adding-tooltips-to-gridview-headers.html.aspx